# Fixed Positioned Element Not Acting As Expected

Tags: css, position

Fixed position is suppose to keep elements at a certain position even when the document is scrolled down or up. However, I can't get this behavior to work on my [website](http://earnwhileyousleep.x10host.com/index.html).

I'm working on a loading element to show the users that the videos on the page have not loaded yet. However, I can't get the text "Loading..." to stay at that position. This is not the first time I had problems with fixed positioning on this page. I've tried to change the absolute positioning on the menu to fixed as well but it wouldn't work.

The css for this text is:

```
#loading {
    font-size: 2em;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: A little strange to have full of webkit only properties and in step 1 say "Download firefox" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches I see here:

1. **Either** remove `position: relative;` from the `#skel-panels-pageWrapper`, as well as `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` suggested by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202180/1069604).
2. **Or** move the `#loading` div outside the `#skel-panels-pageWrapper` and put it directly in the `body`, preferably at the very end to spare any problems with other `relative/absolute` elements that might collide with the `#loading` by the same `z-index` property.

The second one I'd find more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Place the loading div above of the "skel-panels-pageWrapper" if you can, than it works.
The probelm seems to be this one here

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

When you disble the line, it also works.